# What are some ways to offer stats to users?

Tags: zoo-visitor, users

I would like to offer stats such as "your article was read 50 times, your profile was viewed 25 times." I know Zoo Visitor does this, but are there alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EE has [**native entry tracking tags**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/entry_tracking.html).

> ExpressionEngine lets you track how many times a channel entry has been “viewed” on a particular page. Up to four different instances of the view counter can be used (each on a different page), enabling you to track different aspects of an entry independently. For example you can use view counter “one” to track views on your comments page and view counter “two” to track views on your permalink page.
>
> Note: The view tracking counter works in conjunction with the {exp:channel:entries} tag. Although you can show the number of views in any instance of your channel entries tag, the counter will only increment on pages that show a single-entry pages. Single entry pages are ones that show only a single entry, specified dynamically by the ID number or URL Title in the URL, such as comment or permalink pages.
>
> Also Note: If you have page caching enabled this feature will not work.

---

Additionally, Solspace has the [**Tracker**](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/tracker/) module

> Tracker is a flexible application that allows you to track views for channel entries from site visitors. Instead of recording views per page, Tracker records views for each time a specific channel entry is loaded. Stats are available in intervals of days, weeks, months, and years. You can view a variety of overall and filtered down stats in the Tracker module control panel area, as well as entry-specific stats in the publish page using the Tracker field type.
>
> On the front end in your templates, you can display ranked lists of entries, stats for each entry, and charts/graphs for each entry. The tracking code that is placed in your templates is also available as a pixel image so you can track views on cached pages.

Comment: Just wanted to add something to what Anna said. If you use entry view tracking and need it on a non-standard single entry page, check out this hidden config option: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/general/hidden_configuration_variables.html#relaxed-track-views